# Jquery slider space/margin issue

Tags: jquery, css, whitespace, margin, slide

I'm having an issue with a jquery slider script. When the slideshow reaches the last div it will leave a space. I believe this is due to the script calculating how much margin is needed, I may be wrong though. How do I correct this? I would like the last div to be snug up against the page. jsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/c3v6R/26/

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the white space in the left, the reason why it's showing it is because your slider doesn't have a container. If you put it inside a div with [overflow:hidden](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) and a determined width it should only show the content inside that box.